# Get specific Url value

Tags: jquery

How can I get this value ***ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1*** from this Url http://www.dentalo.se/bokning/ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the domain name might change, you can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var urlParts = window.location.href.split('/'),
    thePart = urlParts[(urlParts.length - 1)];
```

This will now populate `thePart` with:

```
"ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1"
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/4qweB/)

Note the jsFiddle uses a string to represent the URL...

Comment: Perfect works like a charm. :D

Comment: Glad to help, you might want to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.dentalo.se/bokning/", "");
```

The result will be:

> ea297dbd-cdc1-40c4-8a01-cbd7e4854fb1

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/R46Up/

What it does is, it gets the URL and replaces the before part of the URL and provides you with the remaining one.

Comment: Nice solution, but if the page is ever migrated to another directory or domain, this will fail.

Comment: Yes surely it will fail! But it was just a solution for this one..:)

Answer (score 0):

Anothe solution:

```
var mylocation = window.location.href.split('/');
mylocation = mylocation[mylocation.length-1];
```

Comment: oh lol, I posted and haven't seen it ^^'

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy you can try this code:

```
var URL = $(location).attr('href');
var value = URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(value);
```

Comment: There really is no need to use jQuery here...